# Want to scrape flipkart

Tags: python, mongodb, web-scraping, scrapy

In short, I have to scrape Flipkart and store the data in Mongodb.

Firstly, use [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/lp/try2-in) to get yourself a free managed Mongodb server. Test if you are able to connect to it using python's library pymongo.

Secondly, install [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) and use its documentation to get yourself friendly with scraping using the Scrapy Framework.

Then, go to the following 2 urls

Men's Topwear   https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/topwear/pr?sid=clo%2Cash&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen

Women's Footwear   https://www.flipkart.com/womens-footwear/pr?sid=osp,iko&otracker=nmenu_sub_Women_0_Footwear

Each page has 40 products and you have to scrape upto 25 pages from each starting Url (approx. 2000 products) and store the data in Mongodb (database: , collection: flipkart). The data should get inserted in Mongodb directly from the Scrapy framework using Scrapy Mongodb Pipelines.

Each product you scrape should have the following data:

- `name` [store as string]
- `brand` [store as string]
- `original_price` [store as float]
- `sale_price` [store as float]
- `image_url` [store as string]
- `product_page_url` [store as string]
- `product_category` [store as string] [ it can contain 2 values "women footwear" or "men topwear" ]

But I am able to scrape only brand, title sale price and product url the original price has two string and its getting mismatch and i am not able to save the data in mongodb is anyone can help me in this.

```
from ..items import FlipkartItem
import json
import scrapy
import re


class FlipkartscrapySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'flipkartscrapy'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/topwear/pr?sid=clo%2Cash&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen&page={}',
        'https://www.flipkart.com/womens-footwear/pr?sid=osp%2Ciko&otracker=nmenu_sub_Women_0_Footwear&page={}']

        for url in urls:
            for i in range(1,25):
                x = url.format(i)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=x, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        items = FlipkartItem()
        name = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "IRpwTa", " " ))]').xpath('text()').getall()
        brand = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_2WkVRV", " " ))]').xpath('text()').getall()
        original_price = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_3I9_wc", " " ))]').xpath('text()').getall()
        sale_price = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_30jeq3", " " ))]').xpath('text()').getall()
        image_url = response.css('._1a8UBa').css('::attr(src)').getall()
        product_page_url =response.css('._13oc-S > div').css('::attr(href)').getall()

        items['name'] = name
        items['brand'] = brand
        items['original_price'] = original_price
        items['sale_price'] = sale_price
        items['image_url'] = image_url
        items['product_page_url'] = 'https://www.flipkart.com' + str(product_page_url)
         
        yield items
```

Original price output coming like this `original_price`:

```
['₹', '999', '₹', '1,499', '₹', '1,888', '₹', '2,199', '₹', '1,499', '₹', '1,069', '₹', '1,099', '₹', '1,999', '₹', '2,598', '₹', '1,299', '₹', '1,999', '₹', '899', '₹', '1,099', '₹', '1,699', '₹', '1,399', '₹', '999', '₹', '999', '₹', '1,999', '₹', '1,099', '₹', '1,199', '₹', '999', '₹', '999', '₹', '1,999', '₹', '1,287', '₹', '999', '₹', '1,199', '₹', '899', '₹', '999', '₹', '1,849', '₹', '1,499', '₹', '999', '₹', '999', '₹', '899', '₹', '1,999', '₹', '1,849', '₹', '3,499', '₹', '2,397', '₹', '899', '₹', '1,999']
```

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: @jsotola it could also be an assessment as part of a job application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

items['original_price'] = [original_price[i]+original_price[i+1] for i in range(0, len(original_price), 2)]

Answer (score 1):

The `original_price` HTML is: `<div class="_3I9_wc">₹<!-- -->2,199</div>`. Since it is being broken up by an HTML comment (`<!-- -->`), Xpath is returning 2 elements instead of one.

A solution to this:

```
original_price = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_3I9_wc", " " ))]').xpath('text()').getall()
original_price = [price for price in original_price if price != '₹']
```

As a side note: you could also simplify your original_price xpath code: `original_price = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_3I9_wc", " " ))]/text()').getall()`